# How can i use IFNULL in Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, ifnull

I want to use `IFNULL()` in such a way that I can select the record containing NULL or, if a value is present, then select the record matchinga particular value.

My query is:

```
SELECT (@v:=2) AS Row, CL.LeaveTypeId, CL.NumberOfLeave
FROM `CompanyLeave` CL
WHERE(IFNULL(CL.EmploymentType,0)=3);
```

column `EmploymentType` can contain either an `Integer` or `NULL`.

I want to select the record matching the specified value, or, if none matches, then the record containing `NULL`.

Comment: What do you mean with `return something else`?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your code is correct, should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am interpreting the question as a prioritization.  If a record with `3` exists, choose that.  Otherwise, choose the one that is `NULL`, if it exists.

If so, this might do what you want:

```
SELECT (@v:=2) AS Row, CL.LeaveTypeId, CL.NumberOfLeave
FROM `CompanyLeave` CL
WHERE CL.EmployementType = 3 or CL.EmployementType IS NULL
ORDER BY (CL.EmployementType = 3) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This will return the row with `3`, if present.  Otherwise, it will return a row with `NULL`, if one exists.

Comment: Thanks  I used this way in query and I got the result what I want.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `IFNULL(CL.EmploymentType, 3)` basically means: if `CL.EmploymentType IS NULL` then use `3` instead. The original value of `CL.EmploymentType` is used if it is not `NULL`.

If I understand correctly your question, you need to select the rows having `NULL` or `3` in the column `CL.EmploymentType`.
The query is:

```
SELECT (@v:=2) AS Row, CL.LeaveTypeId, CL.NumberOfLeave
FROM `CompanyLeave` CL
WHERE IFNULL(CL.EmploymentType, 3) = 3;
```

**Update:**

If only one row must be returned (the one having `3` being preferred over those having `NULL`) then the rows must be sorted using a criteria that puts the `NOT NULL` value in front and a `LIMIT 1` clause must be added.

MySQL [documentation about `NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) says:

> When doing an `ORDER BY`, `NULL` values are presented first if you do `ORDER BY ... ASC` and last if you do `ORDER BY ... DESC`.

The updated query is:

```
SELECT (@v:=2) AS Row, CL.LeaveTypeId, CL.NumberOfLeave
FROM `CompanyLeave` CL
WHERE IFNULL(CL.EmploymentType, 3) = 3;
ORDER BY CL.EmploymentType DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IF statement** instead of **IFNULL()**

```
IF(condition, expres1, expres2)
```

It means that if condition is satisfied then return expres1 else expres2

```
SELECT (@v:=2) AS Row, CL.LeaveTypeId, CL.NumberOfLeave
FROM `CompanyLeave` CL
WHERE IF(CL.EmploymentType IS NULL, 0, CL.EmploymentType) = 3;
```